# Re-use a component between multiple apps

Tags: angular

At work, we will, in the future, build multiple SPA apps to replace our old ones. We currently are considering Angular. Now I want to understand if I have the wrong approach, or if it is possible to create components that can be re-usable across all of our apps. An example :

Each app will have a nav-bar. I don't want to re-write the nav-bar in each of them, I would simply like to add a  component that would fetch its data from our database. If we want to update the nav-bar, we only do it at one place and all the apps benefit from it.

I'm not quite sure what the course of actions is in this case and I really don't have enough knowledge in Angular to know how to achieve this.

Comment: When you say "apps" are you referring to "modules" of your SPA application?

Comment: I'm referring to a whole new Angular app. Here's also one of the things i'm not sure : we're gonna have 100+ apps. Should they all be inside the same Angular project? I feel like this would be a mess when there are multiple developers.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean concrete different apps, actually it depends on the complexity of your components. But generally **YES**, I can suggest a private **npm repository** **[(you can see several possibilities here)](https://medium.com/engenharia-noalvo/ways-to-have-your-private-npm-registry-and-a-final-diy-solution-eed001a88e74)** . Create a simple component, export it there, and then install it as a dependency in all your apps. Thus, once you want to change it, make a new release to the generic component and launch an update on it for your apps, and that's it merely. However, I return and insist on the complexity of your components, since they should be very generic, robust and flexible to changes per app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use angular cli to create a library with the following command

```
ng g library your-lib-name
```

then you publish it whether you want it private or public
and finally just install it in any of your apps

here is a link that may help you:
https://medium.com/@faxemaxee/building-and-publishing-angular-libraries-using-angular-cli-140057d21101

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports large apps with its modularisation feature. Each of your 100+ apps can each serve as a module on its own in angular. Angular modules operate independently of each other and each loads independently too.

You can also share a component across your various modules, making it easy to update and manage across all your modules.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some reading, what I understand is that I have 2 ways of achieving my need :

1. Create one big Angular app and use the power of Modules and lazy-loading to manage everything. By having a common module, I would be able to have shared components between the modules and be able to re-use components for authentication, nav-bar, notifications, etc.
2. Create multiple Angular apps. Re-usable components should be coded inside a library and deployed somewhere on a public or private npm. Then when I need the module I install it inside my app.

First option seems to be better and simpler to manage, but needs some good management when many people work on the front-end apps at the same time. In the second one, each app has its context and you're not impacting anyone else's development.